# using emacs semantic with ede and company-mode to complete and navigate

Tags: c++, emacs

I followed http://tuhdo.github.io/c-ide.html#orgheadline33 tutorial to build a c/c++ IDE using emacs.

However I have problems using semantic to complete with company-mode and navigate. The thing is that when I try to tell semantic where is other library or codes is using semantic-add-system-include, it only works with c++ includes.

If I add `(semantic-add-system-include "~/mylib")`, semantic won't parse the files in ~/mylib and so company won't work. But if I use `(semantic-add-system-include "/usr/include/c++/4.5.2/")` this will work. How do make it work with other codes or headers?

I also tried to use EDE. My project directory is like this:

```
/project root  
    /lib1  
    /lib2
```

and I tried

```
(ede-cpp-root-project "myproject"
                      :file "/home/user/myproject/Makefile"
                      :include-path '("/lib1"
                                      "/lib2")
                      )
```

and

```
(ede-cpp-root-project "myproject"
                      :file "/home/user/myproject/Makefile"
                      :system-include-path '("/home/user")
                      )
```

However, when I type

```
#include <myproject/lib1/xx.h>
```

in my source file, semantic won't parse the correct file and offer the complete candidate.

I just want semantic parse the correct file when I type `#include <myproject/lib1/xx.h>`. Can I achieve this with semantic or/and EDE?

Answer (score 1):

I have something like the following in my `semantic-mode-hook`.  The variable `semantic-dependency-system-include-path` is mode-local.  Try redefining `your-c-include-dirs` or `your-c++-include-dirs` in the following.

```
(defun your-semantic-hook ()
  ;; these are buffer-local
  (mapc (lambda (dir)
          (semantic-add-system-include dir 'c-mode))
        your-c-include-dirs)
  (mapc (lambda (dir)
          (semantic-add-system-include dir 'c++-mode))
        your-c++-include-dirs))

(add-hook 'semantic-mode-hook 'your-semantic-hook)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer jenesaisquoi. I am sorry that I am not familiar with elisp. I just reaplaced `your-c++-include-dirs` with directories like `"/home/user/mylib"` and when I restart emacs there is an error. Wrong type argument: stringp, 47. I don't know what this means. Is my code correct? By the way, since this function make the system include file buffer-local, I cannot specify different include files for different projects. This is frustrating.

Comment: Define that as a list, eg, `'("~/mylib" "blah/blah")`.  That variable is already defined in the library as buffer-local, this function doesn;t that that.  If you have project specific directories you can use .dir-locals.el or another method for project variables.

Comment: I retried the EDE method and it works. It failed because I test the completion in a .h file, which is opened in c-mode by emacs by default. After I changed the default mode for .h file to c++-mode, EDE works well. For the `semantic-add-system-include` problem, I tried your add-hook method. I defined a function which execute my `semantic-add-system-include` command and it is evaluated when semantic-mode initialized and it works. I don't know why I can't write it in init.el straightly. Anyway, thank you very much.